# Characteristics of wavepackets

Tags: quantum-mechanics, waves, gravitational-waves, solitons, phase-velocity

I've been learning about wave packets and group velocities recently and had a question. Using simple trigonometric identies, we can show that the super position of two traveling waves with frequency-wavenumber pair $(k \pm \Delta k,\omega \pm \Delta \omega)$ leads to a carrier wave described by the parameters $(k,\omega)$ with a large scale modulation envelope given by the parameters $(\Delta k,\Delta \omega)$. The wave velocity associated with the modulation is then $\Delta \omega/ \Delta k$. Setting $\Delta k \rightarrow 0$, gives us the group velocity $v_g = d\omega/dk$.

The question I have is: suppose I have a given/prescribed dispersion relation $\omega = \omega(k)$ defined on the real line, $k\in\mathbb{R}$. I can find the phase and group velocities but I want to know what the modulation envelope looks like. It will most likely not be a simple traveling wave and will have a higher harmonics, but how can I get it?

Comment: Yes, there are also some mathematical descriptions of it. This is a good description: http://www.lboro.ac.uk/microsites/maths/research/preprints/papers02/02-25.pdf

Comment: This is an application in quantum mechanics: http://quantummechanics.ucsd.edu/ph130a/130_notes/node83.html

Comment: This is not a well-defined question. The shape of the wavepacket depends on the way it's constructed. You get a beat-like sinusoidal envelope if you superpose two frequencies. You can also get a gaussian envelope, or a sharp square envelope, etc.

Comment: I am not insisting that it be sinusoidal, but I would like a spatial description of the envelope. A Gaussian also has a representation in the Fourier domain as does a square envelope, in fact any $f\in L^1$ has Fourier representation. In particular, what I am looking for is a relation between the Fourier components of the signal and the Fourier components of the envelope.

Comment: The amplitude profile vs. time/frequency is different than the dispersion relation (which only connects the frequency to the wavenumber and vice versa).  As knzhou said, you would need to provide more information about the wave itself for anyone to answer this question.  For instance, would the power spectrum look like a power-law or a single, monochromatic peak?

Comment: I have the power spectrum given. It is a piecewise power-law. Is there a way to capture the envelope using this information and the dispersion relation? I want to avoid resorting to the Hilbert transform.

Comment: If you have the power spectrum, then you know $\lvert A\left( \omega, \mathbf{k} \right) \rvert^{2}$, right?  So you should be able to, at least partially, get an idea of the wave properties.  I doubt you will be able to reconstruct the waveform itself in a time series (unless you have more information that you are not sharing) though.

Comment: Thanks, I suppose not then. I wanted some wave characteristics because it is difficult to put a finger down on the physical relevance of the group velocity when I don't know what the associated waveform looks like. Maybe the relevant question is: does the group velocity represent any important physics when your power spectrum does not have a sharp peak (around which you can linearize the dispersion relation)?

Comment: You can say that $\lvert A \rvert^{2}$ propagates at $V_{g}$.  In the frame moving at $V_{g}$, you will observe constant $k$ and $\omega$ but phase fronts (i.e., wave crests) can move past you if $V_{g} \neq V_{ph}$.  You can think of $k$ and $\omega$ as the _density_ and _flux_ of waves, respectively.